# Unable to list versions for java library from jcenter

Tags: gradle, jcenter

Unable to list versions for java library from jcenter, which causes the `./gradlew dependencyUpdates` to fail with the following error

```
Cause 2: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Failed to list versions for se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/se/emilsjolander/stickylistheaders/maven-metadata.xml.
        at org.gr
```